# Does linq query will be the same if i change db?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Just in case, i would like to move from sql server to postgres and i am alredy using a sql server with EF then do i need to change the code?

Does all query using EF will be the same?

Comment: You will need to install the provider: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework6.Npgsql/

Comment: linq has NOTHING to do with the underlying db. linq is the language for queries against your BL objects. those BL objects are mapped onto tables (or sets of tables) in the EF models. those models are used by the EF provider to translate the IQueryable to a query (along with dematerializing and materializing result sets). If you can map accordingly and have the correct provider installed, your LINQ queries can stay the same no matter what DB instance is underlying.

Answer (score 0):

All data sources that implement the `IQueryable<T>` generic interface can be queried through LINQ in the same way.